# Two Columns Sum if

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an "amount column" and a "Date Vouchered column".  What I would like is a formula in a "summary cell" that will show the sum total of the amounts once a date vouchered has been placed next to the amount.  For instance, as soon as 10/21/14 was placed next to the $1.11 below, the forumla would sum $3.36+$1.11 but exclude $109.00, as it does not have a voucher date as of yet.

I wanted to use an embeded if statement....but, it seems cumbersome.

```
 Amount    Date_Vouchered
  $3.36     10/20/2014
  $1.11     10/21/2014
$109.00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Excel's [=SUMIF](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/sumif-HP005209292.aspx) formula.

For your example, use `=SUMIF(Date_Vouchered,">0",Amount)`.  This will SUM everything in the amount column, IF the date column is greater than 0.